# How to calculate height of custom UITableViewCell by using UILabel's content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

How can I calculate height of a custom `UITableViewCell` by using `UILabel`'s content in table view cell?

Comment: How many cells do you have in your table ?

Comment: Ten custom cells and number of rows are dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //your data string

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(yourLabel.frame.size.width, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size;

    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize boundingBox = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint 
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:yourLabel.font}
                                            context:context].size;

    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

    return size.height;
}
```